# Allow Ad hoc updates to system catalogs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to disable/delete this trigger `RG_SQLLighthouse_DDLTrigger` at the `sys.server_triggers` table.

I tried to run any of these two statements:

```
update sys.server_triggers set is_disabled = 1 where name = 'RG_SQLLighthouse_DDLTrigger'
delete sys.server_triggers where name = 'RG_SQLLighthouse_DDLTrigger'
```

but the following error message appeared

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

I tried to run `sp_configure 'allow updates', 1` but the same problem exists.

Comment: That's a RedGate trigger. Might I suggest talking to them for support; they have a very good support team from my experience. I suspect, however, that this is an  XY Problem; why do you want to disable the trigger in the first place (If I recall it's part of the DLM Dashboard), so you very likely *want* that trigger active when you make a change to the schema.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I am working now on migrating a table from disk to be In-Memory table, and this trigger is preventing that table in memory, so, I wanna disable it temporarily.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the trigger with DISABLE TRIGGER (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement?

Comment: I already found another solution and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code to completely remove the trigger, and it works properly with me!
`DROP TRIGGER RG_SQLLighthouse_DDLTrigger ON ALL SERVER;`